# Strangely cscript does not save xlsx as xlExcel8 and failed silently

Tags: vba, vbscript, ms-office

I was using MSOffice2010 and cscript (Windows Script Version 5.8), trying to do things as simple as:

```
  1. Open a native xlsx file 
  2. Save it as xls file (xlExcel8)
```

What I did was:

## xcx.vbs

' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff198017(v=office.14).aspx

```
  Const xlExcel8 = 56

  Set wdo = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

  Set wdoc = wdo.Workbooks.Open("c:\path\to\foo.xlsx")

  wdoc.SaveAs "c:\path\to\bar.xls", xlExcel8

  wdoc.Close

  wdo.Quit
```

To run it:

> cscript xcx.vbs

Then, the script finished without any error. But I can't find `c:\path\to\bar.xls` at all.

I'd appreciate if some one could show me a right way to go, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that you have not error on the first line. Maybe you have `On Error Resume Next` above this code? Try this:

```
Const xlExcel8 = 56
```

But if that constant is already defined, you'll get error too like "Name redefined", and if so, just remove that line.

Comment: Panayot, thanks for the reply, I was just too hurry to raw type things on another computer of my code :) And the problem is still there with the correct const with "=". To avoid misunderstanding, I have got the question **updated**.

Comment: I see, well, then my answer not help at all :)

Answer (score 0):

This really drove me crazy! The counterpart simlar code for docx<->doc and
pptx<->ppt just worked smoothly.

And I found a phenomenon (rather than workround) that the file will be
saved if an extra *wasted* line is added ahead the target 'SaveAs'
line. (see the commented code below).

Besides:

1. The wasted SaveAs doesn't really have function to save things(as the
   original problem)
2. The target SaveAs doesn't work if the wasted SaveAS is trying to save as a file of same format as the target.

I am really dizzy now and tend to consider a MS Excel bug, how's that
sound?

```
Const xlExcel8          = 56
Const xlOpenXMLWorkbook = 51

Set wdo = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set wdoc = wdo.Workbooks.Open("c:\path\to\foo.xlsx")

' This works, but only to save as bar.xls, which "resolved" my original problem
wdoc.SaveAs "c:\path\to\bar.xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook 'Sacrificed line to *activate* the following line of saving ...
wdoc.SaveAs "c:\path\to\bar.xls",  xlExcel8

' This works, but only to save as bar.xlsx, 
' wdoc.SaveAs "c:\path\to\bar.xls",  xlExcel8  'Sacrificed line to *activate* the following line of saving ...
' wdoc.SaveAs "c:\path\to\bar.xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook

' While this doesn't work at all
' wdoc.SaveAs "c:\path\to\bar.xls",  xlExcel8 
' wdoc.SaveAs "c:\path\to\bar.xls",  xlExcel8

wdoc.Close

wdo.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Const xlExcel8 = 56

wdoc.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "c:\path\to\bar.xls", xlExcel8
```